# How to get control nav on top of flexslider?

Tags: html, css, slider, flexslider

I am new to flexslider (http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider) and having difficulty getting the control nav to be on top of the slider image. I would like it to be in the bottom right-hand corner of the images. But no matter what I seem to do with the styling it always defaults to underneath the slider. You can see the website here: http://dakar.bournemouth.ac.uk/~hmonaghan/

Would appreciate any help, cheers!

HTML:

```
<div id="header" class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
<li>
    <div class="slidertext-holder">
    <div class="slidertext">
        <h1>"Donec auctor volutpat lorem, nec cursus augue congue ac. Curabitur malesuada lacinia lorem..."</h1>
        <h2>WARREN MOORE</h2>
    </div>
    </div>
    <img src="images/headerfootball.png">
</li>
<li>
    <div class="slidertext-holder">
    <div class="slidertext">
        <h1>"Duis non metus ipsum. Maecenas sit amet risus ut ligula tempus commodo a in justo."</h1>
        <h2>SOMEONE ELSE</h2>
    </div>
    </div>
  <img src="images/headerfootball.png">
</li>
<li>
    <div class="slidertext-holder">
    <div class="slidertext">
        <h1>"Luke, I am your father."</h1>
        <h2>DARTH VADER</h2>
    </div>
    </div>
  <img src="images/headerfootball.png">
</li>
</ul>
<ol class="flex-control-nav">
    <li><a class="active">1</a></li>|
    <li><a class="">2</a></li>|
    <li><a class="">3</a></li></ol>
```

CSS:

```
.ul slides {
margin-bottom:-0.5%;
}

.flex-control-nav {
color:#FFF;
margin-left:20%;
width:35%;
font-family: Proximanova Regular;
position:absolute;
}

.slidertext-holder {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.slidertext {
width:35%;
margin-left:55%;
position: absolute;
bottom: 10%;
}
```

Sorry, have updated to add code.

Comment: do you have any code to provide? Always provide with code pof what you've got so far.

Comment: You should be able to do this pretty easily with a custom skin [assuming you're using a Spark Slider].  Can you specify which component you are using? HSilder?  VSlider?  Or the MX Slider?

Comment: @Reboog711, I'm sorry but I have no idea what you mean, I'm using Flexslider which you can find here: http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

Comment: @pixelen Since you tagged this with Flex; which is for the Adobe/Apache UI Framework.  With no code; I assumed you were using Adobe or Apache Flex.  My comment would have made more sense in that context.  I will remove the Flex tag.

Comment: @Reboog711 Ah I see, I'm sorry, I broke up flex and slider so people could find it more easily, I forgot about Adobe Flex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
.flex-control-nav {
  bottom: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that has worked, but it's now pushing the slider text up to the top and off the slider.

Comment: It's doesn't at me when I change it from the chrome inspect element panel.

Comment: I just fixed that :D but now the control nav isn't changing the slides... it's always something!

Comment: Try to remove controlsContainer: ".flex-control-nav", manualControls: ".flex-control-nav a" when you load the flexslider.

Comment: @Laxmana that doesn't fix it, it just puts the default control nav back in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `z-index` of the `.flex-control-nav` to a big number ie `z-index: 1000;`. That's way the control bar will be shown on top of slider.

More about z-index : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: I actually did try fiddling about with z-index, but removed it when it didn't seem to make a difference. Seems it only works when uploaded to the server for some reason!

Comment: I don't know why really :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with responsive design you cannot use css to positionning the control nav div who is rendered under the slide... to move the control on top of slide (like views slideshow cycle option), you have to go in flexslider settings (configuration>media>flexslider), edit the option set and go to «Advanced options» tabs. There is a field called «Controls container (Advanced)» where you can specified the class or id of a container to receive the controls! If you dont have any div to use add one manually in the header of your view ex:  and simply specify .flex-control in the control container field... Hope my explaination are clear!

Comment: Hi! Welcome to [so]! You could try to improve the readability of your answer by structuring it in paragraphs and eventually use code formatting and so an!